# XML-RPC message format trouble

Tags: python, web-services, xml-rpc

I have a WS (ZOPE/PLONE) that accept some XMLRPC calls.

So, I write a python snippet of code for do a call to WS and do something.

I follow messagge format that I found [here](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html), and that's my snippet of code:

```
import httplib

def queryInventory():
    try:
        xmlrpc_envelope = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'\
                        '<methodCall>'\
                        '<methodName>easyram</methodName>'\
                          '<params>'\
                            '<param>'\
                              '<value>%s</value>'\
                            '</param>'\
                          '</params>'\
                        '</methodCall>'        

        params = '<EasyRAM>'\
             '<authentication><user>EasyRAM</user><pwd>EasyRAM</pwd><hotel>52</hotel></authentication>'\
             '<operation type="QueryInventory" rate="master"><date from="2012-03-10" to="2012-03-10" /><date from="2012-03-22" to="2012-03-22" /></operation>'\
             '</EasyRAM>'

        data = xmlrpc_envelope % params
        print data
        headers = {"Content-type": "text/xml"}
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('myHost')
        aa = '/ws/xmlrpc/public/EasyRAM'
        conn.request("POST", aa, data, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        print "EasyRAM.queryInventory() response: status=%s, reason=%s" % (response.status, response.reason)
        print "EasyRAM.queryInventory() response=%s" % response.read()
        conn.close()
    except Exception, ss:
        print "EasyRAM.queryInventory() -> Error=%s" % ss
        raise

    return ''

queryInventory()
```

The problem is that i receive the following error message:

> Invalid request The parameter,  params , was omitted from the request. Make sure to specify all required parameters, and try the request again.

Like the parameter isn't passed.

If I modify my snippet by wrapping my parameter (called `params`) into `<string></string>` in that way:

```
 xmlrpc_envelope = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'\
                        '<methodCall>'\
                        '<methodName>easyram</methodName>'\
                          '<params>'\
                            '<param>'\
                              '<value><string>%s</string></value>'\
                            '</param>'\
                          '</params>'\
                        '</methodCall>'
```

something happen, but isn't what I want; in fact my parameter result to be empty (or void, if you like).

Any ideas or suggestions?

**PS.: I know that exists an xml-rpc library for python called xmlrpclib, but I have to develop in that way, because this is an example for client that can't use directly a library like that**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved.

If I add a function like this:

```
def escape(s, replace=string.replace):
s = replace(s, "&", "&amp;")
s = replace(s, "<", "&lt;")
return replace(s, ">", "&gt;",)
```

and before calling the `connection` method I do something like:

```
params = escape(params)
```

Then all goes well.

Hope that could be useful for future purposes